Prove that a quartic polynomial has a root on $[-1,+\infty)$
My question is to prove
$Q(l)=l^4 \left(y^2-3 x^2\right)+l^3 \left(-4 x^3+4 x^2+4 x y^2\right)+l^2 \left(14 x^4-28 x^3+12 x^2 y^2+14 x^2-12 x y^2-2 y^4-2 y^2\right)+l \left(-4 x^5+12 x^4-8 x^3 y^2-12 x^3+20 x^2 y^2+4 x^2-4 x y^4-12 x y^2+8 y^4\right)-3 x^6+12 x^5-9 x^4 y^2-18 x^4+24 x^3 y^2+12 x^3-9 x^2 y^4-20 x^2 y^2-3 x^2+12 x y^4+4 x y^2-3 y^6-2 y^4+y^2$
has a root $l\in[-1,\infty)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$.
The source of the question is this question.

I verified this using Mathematica:
Q=-3 x^2+4 l x^2+14 l^2 x^2+4 l^3 x^2-3 l^4 x^2+12 x^3-12 l x^3-28 l^2 x^3-4 l^3 x^3-18 x^4+12 l x^4+14 l^2 x^4+12 x^5-4 l x^5-3 x^6+y^2-2 l^2 y^2+l^4 y^2+4 x y^2-12 l x y^2-12 l^2 x y^2+4 l^3 x y^2-20 x^2 y^2+20 l x^2 y^2+12 l^2 x^2 y^2+24 x^3 y^2-8 l x^3 y^2-9 x^4 y^2-2 y^4+8 l y^4-2 l^2 y^4+12 x y^4-4 l x y^4-9 x^2 y^4-3 y^6;
Resolve[ForAll[{x,y},Exists[l,-1<=l&&Q==0]],Reals]

Output is true.
I don't know what algorithm was used to get the result.

I tried Intermediate Value Theorem but it is not true that $\left(y^2-3 x^2\right)\cdot Q(-1)<0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$, so I failed.
I think Sturm's theorem may be useful.

Also, I verified $-1$ is the largest $l_1$ such that $Q(l)$ has a root on $[l_1,\infty)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$.
Also, I looked for a similar result: to find the largest $l_2$ such that $Q(l)$ has a root on $(-\infty,l_2]$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$. The result is the root near $32.0991$ of the polynomial $143 l_2{}^6-5346 l_2{}^5+25119 l_2{}^4-26712 l_2{}^3-27000 l_2{}^2+31104 l_2+5616$. I don't know what algorithm was used to get the result.

Sketch of a proof.
If $x = 0$, we have $Q(l) = y^2(l^2+y^2-2l+1)(l^2-3y^2+2l+1)$,
and the statement is true.
In what follows, assume that $x \ne 0$. We split into three cases.

Case 1. $x > 0$ and $y^2 < 3x^2$

We have $Q(\infty) = -\infty$.
Also, we have
$$Q\left(x - 1 + \frac{y^2}{x}\right)
= \frac{y^4(x^2 + y^2)(x^2 + y^2 - 2x)^2}{x^4} \ge 0.$$

Case 2. $x > 0$ and $y^2 \ge 3x^2$

We have $Q(-1) < 0$, and $Q(\infty) = \infty$.

Case 3. $x < 0$

We have $Q(-1) < 0$.
(i) If $y^2 > 3x^2$, we have $Q(\infty) = \infty$.
(ii) If $y^2 \le 3x^2$, we have
$$Q(-2x + 2) =  \left[ 3y^4+(18x^2-22x+3)y^2+15x^4-30x^3+15x^2
\right] $$
$$\times
\left( 3\,{x}^{2}-{y}^{2}-6\,x+3 \right) \ge 0.
$$
We are done.
